# "required" based on assert from validation_groups in forms

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

TL;DR: Required attribute not set according to set validation rules.

validation_groups are a greate way to define what in a form should be validated (and how).
I have this working as expected for the classic "Register" and "Update Profile" Form.

What i dont get to work is a small UI glitch. On all "required" fields, this fields should be  marked with an ***** .

According to the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing) :

> The required option can be guessed based on the validation rules (i.e.
>   is the field NotBlank or NotNull) or the Doctrine metadata (i.e. is
>   the field nullable). This is very useful, as your client-side
>   validation will automatically match your validation rules.

This seems not to work, i can of course overrite the required and if i set it to `false` it is, as expected, not displayed.

But if i use my validate_group for profile_update the password fields are not in the validation_group - and if empty dont get marked as failed element. But the `required` attribute is still set.

So to come to the question - how can the `required` flag be based on the `@Assert` annotation of the entity?

[image]

As you can see on the image, the password fields are marked as "required" but, as intended, are not validated. Again, this is not a validation problem, its just a UI problem with the required attribute.

Dont think it will help much, but here are the relevant (shortend) code parts:

Entity\User:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    use Timestampable;
    use Blameable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=200, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"default"})
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"default"})
     * @Assert\Length(max = "200", groups={"default"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"create"})
     * @RollerworksPassword\PasswordStrength(minLength=6, minStrength=2)
     */
    private $password;

    [....]
}
```

Forms\UserType:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     *
     * @return misc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', 'text', array('label' => 'Firstname'))
            ->add('lastname', 'text', array('label' => 'Lastname'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'EMail'))
            ->add('password', 'repeated', [
                    'type'  => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'invalid_message' => 'Password fields must match',
                    'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'],
                    'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password']
                ]
            );


        [...]
        $builder
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();
                if ($data->getId() == null) {
                    return array('default', 'create');
                }

                return array('default');
            },
            'data_class' => 'Dpanel\Model\Entity\User',
        ));
    }
    [...]
}
```

views\form.html.twig

```
[...]
{{ form(form, {'style': 'horizontal', 'col_size': 'xs', 'align_with_widget': true, 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
[...]
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what actually isn't working based on your post...like, what are you asking more specifically?  I see the * on the password fields.

Comment: exactly, but they souldn't be there :-)

Comment: Oh.  Well by putting a NotBlank() on your password entity you're automatically going to get that requirement...right?

Comment: nope, the notblank is not in use, cause its belonging to a different validation_group. this is what the image should illustrate, if the notblank where acitve, then, as in the email field, there would be a error displayed.

Comment: Can you edit and show me the code where you create your form?  Are you passing the validation group to the form creation?

Comment: its already in there, see the bottom of the userType form

Comment: just to trying to make myself clear, its not a problem with validating, this works as it should for creating and editing. (creating forces password fields, editing doesnt) - but according to my understanding of the documentation the "required" attribute should be "guessed" from the validation. and not be just true by default.

Comment: As a test, could you change password to be a password type instead of a repeated type, and see if it works from there?  I'm wondering if there's an issue with the repeated field and validation groups.

Comment: good idea, but with the same outcome. `->add('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password'))` i also tried to use the default form resource template. but also the label.required is set.

Comment: I would say try removing `@RollerworksPassword\PasswordStrength(minLength=6, minStrength=2)` but that Constraint itself doesn't require there to be data.  I can't imagine it's reading the @ORM and because `nullable=false` it's setting to required, but might be something else you want to try.

Comment: thanks for your patience and your ideas. i guess i will have to dive deeper and debug this require guessing in the form component. maybe webmozart will take a look too.

Comment: ok, intresting, if i use `->add('firstname', null)` and have NO NotBlank annotation then, after cache:clear, `required = false`. But when i set the NotBlank with validation_group, which is not used in the form then `required = true` again. but this is only the case if i force the form type guesser by using null.

Comment: That is interesting.  I've had to dive deeply into the Symfony form components before and I always regret it...the code kind of just spirals down the rabbit hole.  I wonder if you don't use the type guesser if it then doesn't use some of the other automated components.

Comment: i brought out the big guns on it, and try to write a extension which parses the constraints, and set the required fields as it should be. The only problem i face currently is to get the current used validation_group. which it seem is not so easy if it is a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after not finding out why this is not working, i decided to code the functionality myself.

To make this work a big help was found in [this Article](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-conditionally-required-field) and the source of the [JsFormValidatorBundle](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle/blob/master/Factory/JsFormValidatorFactory.php)

What i do is:
Using an FormType Extension which calls a Service Class to get the constraints of the entity.
Once i know which field elements should be required on which are not, i modify the view and set the required variable accordingly.

[image: The Result]

**WARNING**
This code is not extensible tested, and may not work in your configuration!

**Form\Extension\AutoRequireExtension.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Extension;

use Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Subscriber\AutoRequire as AutoRequireSubscriber;
use Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Service\AutoRequire as AutoRequireService;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;


/**
 * Class AutoRequireExtension
 *
 * @package Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Extension
 * @DI\Service("cwd.generic.form.extension.autorequire")
 * @DI\Tag("form.type_extension", attributes={ "alias"="form" })
 */
class AutoRequireExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @var AutoRequireService
     */
    protected $service;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $enabled;

    /**
     * @param AutoRequireService $service
     * @param bool               $enabled
     *
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "service" = @DI\Inject("cwd.generic.form.service.autorequire"),
     *      "enabled" = @DI\Inject("%cwd.genericbundle.form.extension.autorequire.enabled%")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(AutoRequireService $service, $enabled = false)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        if ($this->enabled) {
            $builder->addEventSubscriber(new AutoRequireSubscriber($this->service));
        }
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if ($this->enabled) {
            if (isset($this->service->fields[$view->vars['name']])) {
                $view->vars['required'] = $this->service->fields[$view->vars['name']];
            }

            // Password Repeat Fallback
            if ($view->vars['name'] == 'first' || $view->vars['name'] == 'second') {
                $view->vars['required'] = $this->service->fields['password'];
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

**Form\Subscriber\AutoRequire.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Service\AutoRequire as AutoRequireService;

/**
 * Class AutoRequire
 *
 * @package Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Subscriber
 */
class AutoRequire implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $service = null;

    /**
     * @param AutoRequireService $service
     */
    public function __construct(AutoRequireService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => array('onFormSetData', -10));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onFormSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var Form $form */
        $form   = $event->getForm();
        $this->service->process($this->getParent($form));
    }

    /**
     * @param Form|FormInterface $element
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
     */
    protected function getParent($element)
    {
        if (!$element->getParent()) {
            return $element;
        } else {
            return $this->getParent($element->getParent());
        }
    }
}
```

**Form\Service\AutoRequire.php:**

```
namespace Cwd\GenericBundle\Form\Service;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

/**
 * Class AutoRequire
 *
 * @DI\Service("cwd.generic.form.service.autorequire")
 */
class AutoRequire
{
    /**
     * @var ValidatorInterface
     */
    protected $validator;

    public $fields = array();

    protected $groups = null;

    /**
     * @param ValidatorInterface $validator
     *
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "validator" = @DI\Inject("validator")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new form to processing queue
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function process(Form $form)
    {

        // no need to run for every field
        if ($this->groups === null) {
            $this->groups = $this->getValidationGroups($form);
        }

        // no need to run for every field
        if (count($this->fields) == 0) {
            $this->fields = $this->getValidations($form, $this->groups);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get validation groups for the specified form
     *
     * @param Form|FormInterface $form
     *
     * @return array|string
     */
    protected function getValidationGroups(Form $form)
    {
        $result = array('Default');
        $groups = $form->getConfig()->getOption('validation_groups');
        if (empty($groups)) {
            // Try to get groups from a parent
            if ($form->getParent()) {
                $result = $this->getValidationGroups($form->getParent());
            }
        } elseif (is_array($groups)) {
            // If groups is an array - return groups as is
            $result = $groups;
        } elseif ($groups instanceof \Closure) {
            $result = call_user_func($groups, $form);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function getValidations(Form $form, $groups)
    {
        $fields = array();

        $parent = $form->getParent();
        if ($parent && null !== $parent->getConfig()->getDataClass()) {
            $fields += $this->getConstraints($parent->getConfig()->getDataClass(), $groups);

        }

        if (null !== $form->getConfig()->getDataClass()) {
            $fields += $this->getConstraints($form->getConfig()->getDataClass(), $groups);
        }

        return $fields;
    }

    protected function getConstraints($obj, $groups)
    {
        $metadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFor($obj);
        $fields = array();

        foreach ($metadata->members as $elementName => $d) {
            $fields[$elementName] = false;
            $data = $d[0];
            foreach ($data->constraintsByGroup as $group => $constraints) {
                if (in_array($group, $groups) && count($constraints) > 0) {
                    $fields[$elementName] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $fields;
    }

    /**
     * Gets metadata from system using the entity class name
     *
     * @param string $className
     *
     * @return ClassMetadata
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    protected function getMetadataFor($className)
    {
        return $this->validator->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($className);
    }

    /**
     * Generate an Id for the element by merging the current element name
     * with all the parents names
     *
     * @param Form $form
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getElementId(Form $form)
    {
        /** @var Form $parent */
        $parent = $form->getParent();
        if (null !== $parent) {
            return $this->getElementId($parent) . '_' . $form->getName();
        } else {
            return $form->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

An Up2Date version can be found on https://gitlab.cwd.at/symfony/cwdgenericbundle/tree/master/Form

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I didn't take the time to go through [Rufinus’ own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673607/1668200) in detail. However, here’s a solution which is simpler, especially if you just need it for *one* field:

```php
// UserType.php

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

// ...

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if (in_array('create', $form->getConfig()->getOption('validation_groups'))) {
        $form->add('password');
    }
    else {
        $form->add('password', null, 'required'=>false);
    }
});
```

The idea is to use an [Event Listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) to find out if the `create` validation group is set, and then add the password field with or without `'required'=>false`.